# Problems with some Automation Testing using Before / After / Test

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Problems with some Automation Testing using Before / After / Test
    I'm getting stuck at the browser window, no test is executed...
Not sure why this doesn't work. I've exported some tests from Selenium IDE, exported as Java, edited that stuff in Eclipse, yet still it doesn't work...

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Checkimage {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testCheckimage() throws Exception {
    driver.get("http://");
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.linkText("sign in / up"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.id("login-email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-email")).sendKeys("michael.sinitsin@avid.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-password")).sendKeys("mike1780");
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if ("sign in".equals(driver.findElement(By.id("login-buttons-password")).getText())) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.id("login-buttons-password")).click();
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if ("Tester".equals(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Tester")).getText())) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Tester")).click();
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.id("inputScoreUrl"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.id("inputScoreUrl")).sendKeys("http://www.sheetmusicdirect.com/scorches/smd_000001.sco");
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if ("Enter a URL to a publicly accessible SCO file. No need to URL encode it, just copy and paste it in.".equals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.help-block")).getText())) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.id("submitScoreView")).click();
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.cssSelector("img"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    try {
      assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.cssSelector("img")));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
```

Not sure why this doesn't work. I've exported some tests from Selenium IDE, exported as Java, edited that stuff in Eclipse, yet still it doesn't work...

Comment: I am confused whether it is typo or something else : `if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");`?

Answer (score 0):

Dear Michael Sinitsin,

As I see it you have here several issues:

1. You do not supply a valid URL to the web driver

> replace driver.get("http://"); with a valid URL like driver.get("http://www.google.com");

2. You are exposing your user/password on a public site

Answer (score 0):

Michael Sinitsin,

you should first mention proper URl  driver.get("http://"); And your script is too complex,you could write it in a simplest way.